# taskdef class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp cannot be found using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, ant

I am using Android studio to build a project and use gradle to build it.
This error message is taking so much time to fix. There is no relevant information online to fix.
If anyone has an idea? please share.. thank you for your time.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mySignTask'.

  > taskdef class org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.ssh.Scp cannot be found
  >   using the classloader AntClassLoader[]

Answer (score 0):

[check this out](http://maven.40175.n5.nabble.com/Cause-the-class-org-apache-tools-ant-taskdefs-optional-ssh-Scp-was-not-found-td5848631.html) If memory serves me Ant was replaced with maven and now gradle is the prefered

Answer (score 0):

Some of Ant's tasks require additional 3rd party libraries. In the case of `scp` (and `sshexec`), you'll need `jsch.jar` available in your Ant lib classpath.

For more information, see https://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html#librarydependencies